# One line bash command to find N oldest and newest files in a directory

Tags: bash

I have the following command:

```
files=$(ls -lhrt dirname) && echo $files | head -5 && echo $files | tail -5
```

The idea is to return the oldest and newest 5 files in a directory `dirname`. This returns the requested data - however, the lines are jumbled together.

Is there a way to better format the output? (or perhaps a better way to write this functionality)?

Comment: If you mean that the newest and oldest are intermingled, inserting a short `sleep` command between the outputs should fix that.

Comment: @TomZych, No I mean that the line breaks are missing, so instead of having details displayed (one file per line), the information is displayed as one long string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about adding linebreaks like so:

```sh
files=$(ls -lhrt dirname) && echo -e "${files}\n" | head -5 && echo -e "${files}\n" | tail -5
```

Explanation:

The `-e` flag enables echo to interpret escapes such as `\n` in this example.

`\n` itself is the escape sequence for "new line". So all it does is adding a new line after the echoed variable.

`${ }` is called [Brace Expansion](https://ss64.com/bash/syntax-expand.html). Since I put the string in quotes, `${}` will expand the variable to the string.

Comment: These are all red herrings. `echo "$files"` would suffice. The important part is enclosing the variable expansion in quotes. The `-e`, `\n`, and `${ }` bits are all irrelevant.

Comment: @JohnKugelman Yep, you are right. Didn't know that. yours should be the accepted answer

Comment: FYI, `${}` is *shell parameter expansion*. `$files` and `${files}` are the same thing; the curly braces are optional. They're useful if you have trailing alphanumeric characters, like `${foo}bar`. *Brace expansion* is when you use curly braces without a dollar sign: `foo{bar,baz}` expands to `foobar foobaz`.

Answer (score 2):

Always quote variable expansions to prevent word splitting and globbing. When you leave `$files` unquoted bash's word splitting pass causes the newlines to be lost.

```
files=$(ls -lhrt dirname) && echo "$files" | head -5 && echo "$files" | tail -5
```

There's no real benefit from using the `&&` operators. I'd just write:

```
files=$(ls -lhrt dirname)
echo "$files" | head -5
echo "$files" | tail -5
```

Or, better, swap the `echo`s for `<<<` to avoid unnecessary subprocesses.

```
files=$(ls -lhrt dirname)
head -5 <<< "$files"
tail -5 <<< "$files"
```

Answer (score 2):

## head an tail together

( Without having to store whole output of previous command into one variable )

Nota: along this, I will use top 4 lines and last 4 lines for sample using `seq 1 100..`, but top 5 lines and last 5 lines for samples using `ls -lhrt dirname`.

### First way, by using `head` and `tail` consecutively

if you try:

```
seq 1 100000 | (head -n 4;tail -n 4;)
1
2
3
4
99997
99998
99999
100000
```

Seem do the job, but

```
seq 1 1000 | (head -n 4;tail -n 4;)
1
2
3
4
```

Give wrong answer.

This is due to *buffering*, but [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) let you use unbuffered input:

```
seq 1 12 | { for i in {1..4};do read foo;echo "$foo";done;tail -n 4 ;}
1
2
3
4
9
10
11
12
```

#### Finally

For your request, try this:

```
{ for i in {1..5};do read foo;echo "$foo";done;tail -n 5;} < <(ls -lhrt dirname)
```

must match your need.

### Or by using both together, with help of `tee`

Just look:

```
seq 1 12 | tee > >(tail -n4) >(head -n4)
1
2
3
4
9
10
11
12
```

But this could render strange things on terminal, to prevent this, you could just pipe whole to `cat`:

```
seq 1 12 | tee > >(tail -n4) >(head -n4) | cat
1
2
3
4
9
10
11
12
```

#### So

```
ls -lhrt dirname | tee > >(tail -n5) >(head -n5) | cat
```

must do the job.

## Or even, if you wanna play with [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) and a big variable:

```
files=$(seq 1 12) out='' in=''
for i in {1..4};do
    in+=${files%%$'\n'*}$'\n'
    files=${files#*$'\n'}
    out=${files##*$'\n'}$'\n'${out}
    files=${files%$'\n'*}
done
echo "$in${out%$'\n'}"
1
2
3
4
9
10
11
12
```

#### Then again:

```
files=$(ls -lhrt dirname) out='' in=''
for i in {1..5};do
    in+=${files%%$'\n'*}$'\n'
    files=${files#*$'\n'}
    out=${files##*$'\n'}$'\n'${out}
    files=${files%$'\n'*}
done
echo "$in${out%$'\n'}"
```

## But you could use GNU [sed](/questions/tagged/sed)

```
seq 1 100000 | sed -e ':a;N;4p;5,${s/^[^\n]*\n//;};$!ba;'
1
2
3
4
99997
99998
99999
100000
```

Then

```
ls -lhrt dirname | sed -e ':a;N;5p;6,${s/^[^\n]*\n//;};$!ba;'
```

Comment: There is more than one way! I think `tee` is the more apropriate, efficient and smart.

Answer (score 0):

Even though it was requested for BASH, I just put here the ZSH line

`echo dirname/*(.om[1,5]) dirname/*(.om[-5,-1])`

This returns a list of `files` with the 5 oldest and 5 newest files (based on modification time). Other solutions based on `ls -lrth` might return directories or links or pipes or anything else.

You can replace `echo` with anything, but you requested a way to find the files, hence the correct answer in ZSH is the above glob (no `echo`)

It works like this :

- `dirname/*` : take all mathching strings
- `(` : open glob specifier
- `.` : return only plain files
- `om` : sort them according to modification time
- `[1,5]` return first five or `[-5,-1]` return last five
- `)` : close the glob specifier

More information on zsh globbing can be found here :
http://www.bash2zsh.com/zsh_refcard/refcard.pdf